# How to decide which conditions to keep and which conditions to dissolve into polymorphism

Tags: java, oop

A brief reference: http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html

To clarify my question:

There are too many articles on the internet which talk about using polymorphism instead of inheritance.
If this were true then 'if-elses' and 'switches' should not appear in most of the java code.

The fact that they do either means:

1. There are certain cases where conditionals cannot be transformed into polymorphism.
2. Each of the code with if else had a potential to be refactored but they were not done.

Now my question.

1. Which of the above option is true ?
2. If option 1 is true then 'how to decide if the if-else can be substituted by polymorphism' ?

Comment: Do you mean "using polymorphism instead of inheritance" or "using polymorphism instead of conditionals"?

Comment: Polymorphism makes your code flexible. But if you know that your system will only ever need to deal with two situations, this or that (i.e. if or else), then use conditionals. Why needlessly complicate your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to avoid conditionals that test the type of an object, such as

```
public void doThing() {
    if (myObject instanceof ClassA)
        doSomething();
    else if (myObject instanceof ClassB);
        doSomethingElse();
}
```

The reason we want to avoid such tests is because they are a source of future bugs in our code. When a new class gets added to our system, all such tests have to be reviewed and possibly changed. Sooner or later, we humans make a mistake and then we have buggy code. In additional, it makes our code more complex, and usually slower. In this simple example that is not obvious, but if we were testing a bunch of types in differing ways it would be.

In this case myObject is an instance of a class that both `ClassA` and `ClassB` inherit; lets call that parent class `ClassP`. So we could avoid add a method to `ClassP` called `doSomething` like this

```
class ClassP {
    // lots of ClassP code

    public void doSomething() {
        // basic implementation of method
    }
}
```

Lets assume that this code is fine for `ClassA`, so for a ClassA instance we could just code

```
myObject.doSomething();
```

But for `ClassB` we need different behavior, so we code

```
class ClassB extends ClassP {
    // lots of ClassB code

    public void doSomething() {
        // different implementation of method
    }
}
```

So now we can do

```
myObject.doSomething();
```

for a `ClassB` instance also. We no longer need that conditional.

The powerful thing is that this code will also handle new types that are added to the inheritance hierarchy in the future, without change. So if we now add a class

```
class ClassC extends ClassP {
    // lots of ClassC code

    public void doSomething() {
        // totally different implementation of method
    }
}
```

Then

```
myObject.doSomething();
```

still works, and calls the method in the new class when `myObject` is a `ClassC` instance, without even needing to be recompiled!

There are several kinds of polymorphism, see Wikipedia: [Polymorphism (computer science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) and [Polymorphism in object-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming). As you can see on those pages, this is an area of some debate.

The kind we are using here is called *subtype polymorphism*, and because of the way it can be implemented is also called *dynamic binding*.

Answer (score 1):

The article you linked to explains it pretty well.

Basically, its conditionals that are dependent on a variable's **type** (e.g. `if (foo instanceof Bar) ...`) that are well suited for conversion to polymorphism, not so much "ordinary" conditionals that are dependent on an variable's **value** (e.g. `if (foo == 42) ...`).

Rule of thumb: if you find yourself using `instanceof` or a comparison to `foo.getClass()`, then you may be able to simplify things with polymorphism (but not always). Otherwise, your conditional is probably fine how it is.

Note that performing conditional logic based on a `type` variable or `getType()` method (or something similar) falls under the same rule - you're basically just substituting manual type inference for Java's inbuilt type mechanisms.

A good example might be the classic "Square" and "Circle" classes, each of which is implements/extends a "Shape" interface/class. `Square`s have an `edgeLength`, `Circle`s have a `radius`.

Imagine you want the area of each shape, you might do the following:

```
interface Shape {

}
class Square implements Shape {
    public float edgeLength;
}
class Circle implements Shape {
    public float radius;
}
...
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Shape shape = new Square(); // or new Circle()
    if (shape instanceof Square) {
        Square square = (Square) shape;
        System.out.println("Area: " + (square.edgeLength * square.edgeLength));
    } else if (shape instanceof Circle) {
        Circle circle = (Circle) shape;
        System.out.println("Area: " + (Math.PI * circle.radius * circle.radius));
    }
}
```

Here, replacing the conditional with polymorphism means implementing an `area` method:

```
interface Shape {
    float area ( );
}
class Square implements Shape {
    private float edgeLength;

    float area ( ) {
        return edgeLength * edgeLength;
    }
}
class Circle implements Shape {
    private float radius;

    float area ( ) {
        return Math.PI * radius * radius;
    }
}
...
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Shape shape = new Square(); // or new Circle()
    System.out.println("Area: " + shape.area());
}
```

This example highlights two other interesting points: first, casts to a base class are often also signs that a refactor to polymorphism might be needed. Second, note the improved encapsulation in the second example.

Answer (score 0):

> *1* There are certain cases where conditionals cannot be transformed into polymorphism.
> *2* Each of the code with if else had a potential to be refactored but they were not done.
>
> Which of the above option is true ?

I would assume that every conditional can be refactored into some sort of polymorphic solution but something has to evaluate the conditions at some place. They don't disappear.

For example basically every `switch` e.g.

```
public void doFoo(int foo) {
    switch (foo) {
        case 0:
            System.out.println("Hello");
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("World");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("!");
            break;
    }
}
```

can be turned into a polymorphic solution that hides (almost) all the conditionals.

```
private final Map<Integer, Runnable> switchMap = new HashMap<Integer, Runnable>();
{
    switchMap.put(0, new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    });
    switchMap.put(5, new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("World");
        }
    });
}
private final Runnable defaultCase = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("!");
    }
};

public void doFooPolyMorphed(int foo) {
    Runnable runnable = switchMap.get(foo);
    if (runnable == null)
        runnable = defaultCase;
    runnable.run();
}
```

The conditions are still evaluted, just not explicitly by your code.